# Insert records to mysql database with php using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to added record using a modal. I have use the following code but my record is not added into the database.. help me through pls

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Project/Style/bootstrap.css"/>
     <script src="Style/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container">
    <?php
    include('header.php');
    require_once('Connections/conn.php');

    $sql2= "SELECT * from type where cid='1' ";
    $results =mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);


    ?>

    <div id="main">

    <div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    ++Add Farm Product
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group col-md-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search-text" id="search-text" placeholder="Search By Product Name">
                    </div>
                    </div>

    <div id="result"></div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Farm Product</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

    <form>
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 padding-top-10">
          <label for="proname" class="control-label">Product Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="proname" placeholder="Product Name" name="proname" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-5 padding-top-10">
  <label for="pro-type" class="control-label">Product Type:</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="pro_type" name="pro_type" >
   <option>Select Product type...</option>
    <?php foreach($results as $result): ?>
    <option value= " <?php echo $result['tid'];  ?>" > <?php echo $result['type_name']; ?>
</option>
  <?php endforeach ;?>              
 </select>
 </div>
 </div><br/>

    <div class="row">                       
  <div class="col-md-4 padding-top-10">
  <label for="qty" class="control-label">Quantity:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qty" placeholder="Quantity"  name="qty" />                                                  
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 padding-top-10">
   <label for="price" class="control-label">Unit Price :</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Unit Price" name="price" />                                                                         
</div>
 <div class="col-md-4 padding-top-10">
 <label for="pdate" class="control-label"> Production Date :</label>
 <input type="date" class="form-control" id="pdate" placeholder="Production Date" name="pdate" />
  </div>
</div>                           
    </form>
    </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
  <button type="button" id="add"  name="add"  class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
    <script>


    // haddling the post for adding record
    $('#add').click(function(){

        var proname = $('#proname').val();
        var pro_type = $('#pro_type').val();
        var qty = $('#qty').val();
        var price = $('#price').val();
        var pdate = $('#pdate').val();

        var datas="proname="+proname+"&pro_type="+pro_type+"&qty="+qty+"&price="+price+"&pdate"+pdate;


    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "addpro_exec.php",
           data: datas,
           success:function(data){

        },
         error: function(){

                     }
        });
        });
    </script>
```

The code handling the posted data is below
//addpro_exec.php file

```
<?php
    require_once('Connections/conn.php');
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){

    $proname=$_POST['proname'];
    $pro_type= $_POST['pro_type'];
    //$typname=$_POST['type_name'];
    $qty=   $_POST['qty'];
    $price= $_POST['price'];
    $pdate= $_POST['pdate'];
    $asdate = \date('F');
        $sql="INSERT into product VALUES('','$proname','','$qty','$price','$pdate','','$pro_type','1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty = qty+$qty";
        $sql2= "INSERT into year_estm VALUES('','$proname','$asdate','$qty','') ON DUPLICATE KEY  update   Production_input=Production_input+$qty ";
    $AddProduction=  mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die('Cannot add to production'. mysqli_error($conn));
    $RecAdd= mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die('Cannot add Product' . mysqli_error());
    if($RecAdd){
        header('location:viewfarm.php');
    }

    }

    else{

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: This is difficult to answer because you haven't shown what you've tried for debugging.  Are there any errors?  Do you know if the AJAX call works? Have you checked your console? What happens if you post directly to the url `addpro_exec.php` without using AJAX - does it work then?

Comment: Look at this line, `if(isset($_POST['add'])){...`. `$_POST['add']` is not set, and that's because you're not sending anything as such in your AJAX request. Also, missing `=` here, `... "&pdate"+pdate;`

Comment: It works completely well without ajax,.. am learning ajax for the first time @cale_b

Comment: i thought when all the values in the 'data:' part of my ajax fuction and the type happens to be "POST", the data values will b posted to the form handler,.. ie addpro_exec.php

Comment: with regrads to if i checked the values in console, i did that and i do see my values from the index page console, i also putting the var data in an alert box and and the values in the alert box are showing, i jst dont get it why it is not posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following line in your javascript:

```
var datas="add=1&proname="+proname+"&pro_type="+pro_type+"&qty="+qty+"&price="+price+"&pdate="+pdate;
```

That should fix the problem.

WARNING: Always filter and a properly quote user input before inserting into a database in order to avoid SQL injection hacks.  Use prepared statements to help achieve this.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank You very much.. It has worked properly @mim.ms

Comment: Emphasis on using prepared statements - this is hugely important to prevent attacks!